# How to simplify this indices question? $\frac{3^n -3^{n-1}}{3^n / 3^{n-3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi i got this indices question here $\frac{3^n -3^{n-1}}{3^n / 3^{n-3}}$ 
, I am not quite sure how to proceed
and here's my workings
$\frac{2 * -3^{n-1}}{1/{-3^3}}$
So far I can only do up to here, this does not seem right so I have decided to ask for help. Can someone show some proper working or tell me what I have done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What you have done so far is mostly fine, though the notation $2*-3^{n-1}$ is frowned upon.  It should instead have been written $2\cdot (-3^{n-1})$.  You do have an error in that $3^n/3^{n-3} = 1/3^{-3}$ or rather $3^3$, not $1/(-3^3)$.

Comment: To continue, remember that you can always "add zero" and "multiply by one" without changing anything.  In this case, we can "multiply by one" in the form $\frac{3^{-3}}{3^{-3}}$ and this will get rid of the denominator.

Comment: @JMoravitz why? i thought the first $3^n$ is postive and the second $-3^n$ is negative

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3^n -3^{n-1}}{3^n / 3^{n-3}} =\frac{3^n -3^{n-1}}{3^3} = 3^{n-3}-3^{n-4}$$

if there is a mistake and instead of $/$ must be $-$ then

$$\frac{3^n -3^{n-1}}{3^n - 3^{n-3}} =\frac{3^{n-1}(3-1)}{3^{n-3}(3^3-1)} = 3^{2}{2\over 26}={9\over 13}$$

Comment: hey sorry my bad your first answer is correct but can you explain how did you get $3^3$ for the deniminator

Comment: @Negrawh because $3^n/3^{n-3}=\frac{3^n}{3^{n-3}}=\frac{3^n}{3^{n-3}}\times \frac{3^{-(n-3)}}{3^{-(n-3)}}=\frac{3^3}{3^0}=3^3$

Comment: @JMoravitz hey thank you, can you please tell me what is this $/frac{3^−(n−3)}{3^−(n−3)}$ process called? thanks you!

Comment: I assume you are referring to how I cancelled things there.  It is called "multiplying by one."

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by @greedoid can be further simplified as
$3^{n-3}-3^{n-4}=3^{n-4}(3-1)=2·3^{n-4}.$

(I would have written this as a comment, but my reputation level woudn't allow it)

Comment: ehhh? how did you get (3-1) i dont undertsand

Comment: @Negrawh because $3^{n-3} = 3^1\times 3^{n-4}$